# Django rest framework, ¿What would be the best way to resolve the error, " index list creation error must be integer or chunked, not str" .?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, postman

There is a possibility to solve my problem, please.

I have 3 molds, of which 2 are related.
I am using create on ModelViewSet, which sent the data but I am getting the following error.
(list indexes must be integer or chunked, not str)
Of course I am trying to create a list of objects, but.
¿How would you develop the syntax? With the use of For?

## ModelViewSet

```
class CreateApiModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = EDFSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        
        dano = models.Dano.objects.all()
        return dano

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.data

       
        new_evento = models.Evento.objects.create(
            tabla=data["evento"]["tabla"],
            usuario=models.Usuario.objects.filter(user_id=data["evento"]["usuario"]).first(),
            patio=models.Patio.objects.filter(id=data["evento"]["patio"]).first()
            
            )
        
        new_evento.save()

        # New Dano

        new_dano = models.Dano.objects.create(
            evento=new_evento, 
            observacion=data["observacion"])
        new_dano.save()

        # Model FotoDano With Error.. :(

        foto = []

        for fotos in foto:
            for f in data["fotodanodetail"]["foto"][0]:

            foto_obj = models.FotoDano.objects.get(
                foto=data["fotodanodetail"]["foto"],
                dano=new_dano)
            new_foto_dano.foto.add(foto_obj)

          # Comment
        # new_foto_dano = models.FotoDano.objects.create(
        #     #id=data["fotodanodetail"]["id"],
        #     #foto=data["fotodanodetail"]["foto"], 
        #     dano=new_dano)
        # new_foto_dano.save()


        serializer = EDFSerializer(new_evento)

        return Response(serializer.data)
```

## Serializer

```
# Import Base64
from drf_extra_fields.fields import Base64ImageField

class EDFSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    fotodanodetail = Base64ImageField(required=False)
    
    evento = CrearEventoSerializer()
    fotodanodetail = FotoDanoFiltroSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Dano
        fields = ('evento','observacion','fotodanodetail')
```

## Postman

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on DRF when you have writeable nested serializer best way is override `.create` method of your serializer rather than viewset

for more information checkout drf docs [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers)

All data in `request.data` have str type you must cast like `int(data["evento"]["usuario"])`

Comment: Exactly, that's what the "override create" had heard.
Currently creating the view set works for me, but I can't create a method for: eg max 3 files: /

Comment: ¿Do you think there could be an idea what the syntax for 3 serializers would be using? * Create